# Can someone read object sent with socket.io emit even though it's not printed out for user in frontend

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

So I'm working on node.js app that pushes objects via socket to update user with latest information.

That object has user data populated with it. I'm wondering if someone can see that information somehow even though it's not printed out?

Should I remove sensitive data from object before emitting it via websocket to the frontend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That object has user data populated with it. I'm wondering if someone can see that information somehow even though it's not printed out?

Yes, anyone snooping around in the client with development tools can see what is sent via a webSocket.  For example, one only has to open the debugger and look at the webSocket packets that have been sent.  The same is true for any data sent to the client in any manner.

> Should I remove sensitive data from object before emitting it via websocket to the frontend?

Yes, you should.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, after some googling I actually managed to see web socket data myself.

Answer (score 1):

**Everything** you send to the client, whether using HTTP, socket connections, etc. is all accessible in the client browser. You should always only send the data that is required by your website to run for that specific client and data particular to that client.

With developer tools getting more powerful everyday, it is much more easy to snoop at such data.